# Recursive function in identifying a sentence or word

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone show me a recursive function that tells if the input is a word or a sentence ?
I have made an if statement with this program but the instruction said that it should be recursive

- word = single word
- sentence = more than 1 word
- input: apple
- output: word
- input: red apple
- output sentence

JAVA language

Comment: Can you show us the code so far?

Comment: if (word.contains(" "))
    {
        System.out.println("sentence");
       
    }
    else
    {
         
        System.out.println("word");
    }

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see if an input is a sentence or a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122439/how-to-see-if-an-input-is-a-sentence-or-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that checking if your input contains space is enough - you don't need recursion here

```
private boolean isSentence(String input) {
    return (input.contains(" "))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asking for recursion is stupid here. It is simple to do without. If you must, here is a recursive version:

```
public boolean isSentence(String input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return input.startsWith(" ") || isSentence(input.substring(1));
    }
}
```

`input.substring(1)` is `input` with the first character removed. The rest should be pretty self-explanatory.